# Text messages returning to original phone

Tags: ios

Since updating to iOS6, every time I text my husband, the text comes to my phone. Any idea how to stop this?

Comment: I little more information might be necessary. Does your husband has iOS6 too? Does it give you any kind of error? Does it only happens with your husband? Is it a SMS or an iMessage?

Comment: Is the text also going to his phone or does it only show up on yours?

Comment: Are you actually texting your husband, or are you iMessaging him? In other words, is the text shown in green or blue in the Messages app?

Answer (score 1):

Under **Settings / Messages / Send and Receive**, remove the check mark from your husband's phone number.

Comment: This might not be enough though. They might share the same Apple ID/iCloud account for instance...

Comment: @patrix You can share the same Apple ID and have isolated iMessage.